# Find the complementary number in a list

Tags: r, list

I have a list of lists like this:

[image: My sample data]

How can I find every number from 1-100 that is not in the list(cluster)?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Pictures of data are not every helpful

Comment: specifically, running `dput(cluster)` and pasting the results into your question as a code chunk would work well ...

Answer (score 1):

I believe something like

```
cluster <- list(c(30,37,21), c(10,19,20), c(22, 10, 11))
setdiff(1:100, unlist(cluster))
```

should work.  `unlist()` collapses the list into a single vector of integers; `setdiff(x,y)` finds all the values in `x` that are *not* contained in `y`.

Slightly less efficiently, but more generally

```
v <- 1:100
u <- unlist(cluster)
v[!v %in% u]
```

Answer (score 1):

If `1:100` is the complete space for values in the cluster, maybe you can try

```
(1:100)[-unlist(cluster)]
```

since the values in the cluster can play as indices as well in your case here.